# Twitter HBC: sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-hbc

I am trying to get Twitter HBC to work. I have not much experience with Java, so I tried their examples. But I always get this error message:

```
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

and some other error messages. I found the description to this error, but I don't understand it.

Here is my code:

```
import com.twitter.hbc.ClientBuilder;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.Constants;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.endpoint.StatusesSampleEndpoint;
import com.twitter.hbc.core.processor.StringDelimitedProcessor;
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.BasicClient;
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.Authentication;
import com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.OAuth1;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SampleStreamExample {

    public static void run(String consumerKey, String consumerSecret, String token, String secret) throws InterruptedException {
        // Create an appropriately sized blocking queue
        BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(10000);

        // Define our endpoint: By default, delimited=length is set (we need this for our processor)
        // and stall warnings are on.
        StatusesSampleEndpoint endpoint = new StatusesSampleEndpoint();
        endpoint.stallWarnings(false);

        Authentication auth = new OAuth1("xxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxxx");
        //Authentication auth = new com.twitter.hbc.httpclient.auth.BasicAuth(username, password);

        // Create a new BasicClient. By default gzip is enabled.
        BasicClient client = new ClientBuilder()
            .name("sampleExampleClient")
            .hosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST)
            .endpoint(endpoint)
            .authentication(auth)
            .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(queue))
            .build();

        // Establish a connection
        client.connect();

        // Do whatever needs to be done with messages
        for (int msgRead = 0; msgRead < 1000; msgRead++) {
            if (client.isDone()) {
                System.out.println("Client connection closed unexpectedly: " + client.getExitEvent().getMessage());
                break;
            }

            String msg = queue.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            if (msg == null) {
                System.out.println("Did not receive a message in 5 seconds");
            } else {
                System.out.println(msg);
            }
        }

        client.stop();

        // Print some stats
        System.out.printf("The client read %d messages!\n", client.getStatsTracker().getNumMessages());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String consumerKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        args[0] = consumerKey;
        String consumerSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        args[1] = consumerSecret;
        String token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        args[2] = token;
        String tokenSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
        args[3] = tokenSecret;
        try {
            SampleStreamExample.run(args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3]);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The full Error is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=D:\Programme\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\jre\lib\rt.jar;D:\Eigene Dateien\Projekte\WorldMood\out\production\WorldMood;D:\Eigene Dateien\Projekte\HBC Lib\hbc-core-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\Eigene Dateien\Projekte\HBC Lib\Dependencies\junit-4.8.1.jar;D:\Eigene Dateien\Projekte\HBC Lib\Dependencies\mockito-all-1.8.5.jar;D:\Eigene Dateien\Projekte\HBC Lib\hbc-twitter4j-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.jar;D:\Programme\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.3\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain     SampleStreamExample
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at SampleStreamExample.main(SampleStreamExample.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

Did I mess up something during the import of the libraries or dependencies? Can you guys help?

Thanks very much in advance!

Kajetan

Comment: I found this code `if (msg == null) ` at line 62 considering you are using twitter pull of HBC example. 

I would be helpful if you include your code

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. My code is there...is there an error? Because i can see it!